# Magento - can I be guaranteed that prototype.js will be available included on every page?

Tags: magento, prototypejs

I guess the answer is that it will be included unless it is not included, but...

if I have a custom module, with Block code that returns JavaScript from the _toHtml() method (the JS code will end up on a few pages, which ones is determined by my module's layout file), can I rely on prototype.js being available to my JavaScript? I'd like to think I can as it would save me having to cater for all the event handling variations. I'd like to just use Event.observe.

The first line of my JS could be to include prototype.js, but what if it isn't on the server, or not in the location returned by Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part you can assume it will be there as it is the backbone of all ajax and Javascript in Magento.

If you want to be certain that it will be in there you could remove it from the layout XML files and hard code it directly in the head.phtml file which is located at:

app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourtheme/page/html/head.phtml

Answer (score 0):

you can add it via local.xml that laught last one

```
<reference name="head">
     <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

also you can rename it to secret_prototype.js, so no one other module not delete it from layout or really add form head.phtml

P.S. Very strange question, you have page on magento without prototype?